# How to enable pabbrev-mode only in normal text file

Tags: completion

I want to enable pabbrev-mode for the auto completion only in normal text file (`.txt`) because if for example I'm editing a `.c` source file I already have a package that do this. How can I modify the `.emacs` file to proper handle this issue? Or is there another package that only works on text file?

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your init (`.emacs`) file:

```el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.txt\\'" . pabbrev-mode))
```

Comment: It sounds like `pabbrev-mode` is a *minor* mode.